# http 301 redirect *and* canonical, how do I solve both?

Tags: http, redirect, http-headers, seo

I have the following situation:

Mosts pages of a domain have different urls (print-version, screenversion, …) but same content. They come with a canonical link to the screen-version. Now, I want to change a part of the url for all pages and 301 the old url to the new.

Should I 301 immediately and also update all canonical links to the new ones or should I first cannonical update all links to the new urls, make for some time both urls (old and new) available and after some time 301 the old ones to the new?

Best regards.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about **SEO** which is off-topic at Stack Overflow. Please read ["Which SEO questions should be closed as non-programming/non-admin?"](//meta.stackoverflow.com/a/382618) to better understand when SEO questions are acceptable to ask here (most are not) and where you might be able to get assistance.

Comment: This question might be a better fit at [webmasters.se].